# Notesfactory session add signature to mail body

Tags: java, lotus-notes

I have a successfully working code where i send lotus notes email from java code using notesfactory session

The code is

```
Document email=db.createDocument();
email.appendItemValue("subject",subjectText);
RichTextItem body=email.createRichTextItem("body");
body.appendText(bodytext);
```

And so on..

But i have no idea how to add signature to it.

Comment: Do you talk about Signing the mail (like technically with a certificate) or adding a signature (Best regards...) to the Body of the mail?

Comment: Best regards to the body of the mail

Comment: Where is your code for creating the Body?

Comment: I have updated my question with code..plz refer

Comment: You'd add a line that says body.appendText(signatureText)

Comment: Can i add already created signature from lotus notes???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Signature from Lotus Notes is saved in the CalendarProfile in different Items. 
If the user selected "Richtext" in the Option "Choose the type of signature you would like to use", then the Signature is in a Richtextitem called "Signature_Rich". Then your code would look somehow like this (ATTENTION: I did not check documentation for correct spelling, there might by typos / uppercase / lowercase errors in that code):

```
Document profile=db.getProfileDocument("CalendarProfile");
if (profile.getItemValueString("SignatureOption") == "3") 
{
  RichTextItem bodySign=(RichTextItem)profile.getFirstItem("Signature_Rich")
  body.appendRTItem(bodySign)
}
```

If the user selected "Plain Text" in that option, then you would need to append the content from item "Signature_1":

```
Document profile=db.getProfileDocument("CalendarProfile");
if (profile.getItemValueString("SignatureOption") == "1") 
{
  RichTextItem bodySign=(RichTextItem)profile.getFirstItem("Signature_Rich")
  body.appendText(profile.getItemValueString("Signature_1"));
}
```

It might be necessary that you add some `body.addNewLine(1)` in between to get linebreaks / distance between text and signature.

If the user selected "HTML or Image file", then the thing becomes complicated, as in the item "Signature_2" is the path to a file that has to be attached... I leave it up to you to get the code resulting from SignatureOption = "2"

Comment: Thanx torsten...sorry for late update.but its working. Just one update..profile.getFirstItem("Signature_Rich"); instead of profile.getFirstItem("SignatureRich");

Comment: Just one more question. Now i am trying to directly send emails instead of saving as draft. I tried email.send(true); but it the emails are not visible in sent folder.

Comment: Any suggestion plz

Comment: First: User emal.send(false) as attaching the form is a bad idea. Second: If you want the mail to show in "Sent", then it needs an item "PostedDate". Just set emal.SaveMessageOnSend = true and then emal.replaceItemValue("PostedDate",Current Date / Time)

Comment: My emails are successfully sent...showing in sent folder but receiver is not receiving them

Comment: No, they are NOT successfully sent... Otherwise the receiver would get them... The fact, that the "Send"- method does not throw an error, does not mean, that the mail is really sent, just that the code successfully TRIED to send it: no direct error like "no valid recipients" or "no mail.box" occured. But debugging this is outside of the code: It is within your infrastructure. Cannot be done here at StackOverflow.

Comment: You may only track the message that you have sent.does it mean that the msg is not sent?? But its showing in sent msg

Comment: How to send mail to multiple ids...coz i didentified that when i try to send to multiple id ..it didnt receive

Comment: I am not your personal support hotline. If you have another question: write it down and post it as separate question with enough code to identify the problem...